# Manage logins on a certain page

Tags: authentication

Is it some way that you could manage your logins on a certain page via some other page?

For ex:

You have an account on site A and you would like to track the amount of times you login to that page via site B.

Thanx in advance.

//Richie

Comment: do you have access to both the sites?

Comment: Yes both sites are mine. I would like to have something on my website that keeps track of how many time i´m login on to facebook.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is:

```
1. I'll create a database variable for site A that increments each time the
   site is visited. 
   You can do this by creating a MySQL database and accessing it with PHP 
   from the site.
2. This database can then be accessed from the other site, namely B, which
   will have the count as a field. 
3. For security reasons you can create username and password fields and ask for
   them each time you try to access the count variable.
```

Does this answer your question?
You can find the basics of creating a database [here](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql).

**EDIT :**

You have to create a database with count variable.

 This database can be accessed from both the sites. 

You can use php for this.

 From what you say, I think, you can use one site to increment the count variable and the other to access and show it on the page. 

 Also, you can create 2 more fields, username and password along with count.

 If you have 200 users, create a record for each of them. 

Do you get it?

Comment: Would that work for more users on mine site?  Say that i have a site with 200 members and i would like to show all the members inlog to facebook so i can see who is most and least active on facebook by counting their inlogs.  Would i have to make the variable on their profile page instead of facebook.com?